# SSL Certificate issue to the end user

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, iis, ssl, iis-7.5

I have a web site developed in Asp.Net and it is hosted in cloud. Site is running on https protocol and certificate is issued to domain (E.g. example.com ) and subdomain (*.example.com). It works well if user types example.com or app.example.com. However some user types URL incorrectly. They type something like www.app.example.com. In this case browser displays warning about certificate. It states something like this “This server could not prove that it is www.app.example.com; its security certificate is from *.example.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection”

This is perfectly fine since subject name (or issued to) is not matching since it involves two subdomains i.e. first subdomain is www and another subdomain is app. Many user scare to do that and they will leave the web site. By googling I found, problem can be fixed by regenerating the certificate with additional subject alt names such as *.example.com and *.*.example.com. But IT staff do not want to regenerate the certificate for some reason. Is there any alternative to fix this problem without regenerating certificate. Expectation is that any error message should not be displayed and any extra action should not to be required from the end user.

I have tried with redirect rules in IIS. But they are not working.

**Platform details** – Asp.Net MVC 5, IIS 7.5 and Windows Server 2008 R2 datacenter

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any alternative to fix this problem without regenerating certificate.

No. The certificate must match the name. If the certificate does not match user gets an error. There is no way around it and if there would be one this could be considered a security risk, because without a proper name check man-in-the-middle attacks would be possible.

> I have tried with redirect rules in IIS. But they are not working.

Redirects are done at the HTTP level, which means with https it first needs to establish the SSL connections. If this fails because of the name mismatch then the redirect will not be reached.

Comment: Ok. another way could be create a new site with www.app.example.com on the same server with plain http protocol. Then create a redirect rule on this site (i.e. plain http site) to secure site with appropriate URL i.e. by eliminating www from url. Will it work?

Comment: @Parag : I don't know if this solution work or not but definitely you are defeating purpose of using https as traffic between end user and your intermediate site www.app.example.com will be unsecured.

Comment: I assume that you are having redirects from http to https everywhere, because otherwise users typing "app.example.com" would not not get the https but the http-only version. In this case it is sufficient to fix the redirects so they only point to the domains with the proper certificate. Of course, if the users types `https://www.app.example.com` this will not help, because then it will try to use https and fail.

Comment: @Pankaj. This logic will be used for the user who types incorrect URL i.e. www.app.example.com. In this case user is neither entering http or https. So browser will take the user to 'http://www.app.example.com' . Then from this site (non-secure site) to 'https://app.example.com' (secure site with valid SSL). So here user will redirected from non-secure site to secure site which is ok. User who will type valid url 'https://app.example.com' will not have any problem. But yes I understand user who type 'htttps://www.app.example.com' will encounter same issue.

Comment: @Parag: You didn't get my point. You are using https to secure data which is being transferred over wire. i.e. from user's browser till your web server. If you use intermediate application without https then whats the point in securing your target app with https? You are securing data travel between intermediate app to your target app but what about path between browser till intermediate app?

Comment: @Pankaj Interaction will start from non secure channel (plain http) for the user who enters incorrect URL (i.e. users who are having www in URL). Other users who enter valid url (i.e. URL without www) will never come to non-secure channel. Even in the first case user will be redirected from http to https which I think is common however reverse is not true. Also the purpose of plain http channel is to redirect the user  to secure channel. After that its role is finished and no communication will happen over that channel.

Comment: "Other users who enter valid url (i.e. URL without www) will never come to non-secure channel." - this is not true. There will be a redirect from http to https here to. I suggest you have a look at tools like sslstrip: all they need for transparent man-in-the-middle is a single request with plain http, i.e. the initial redirect is sufficient. But then, if the user is not aware that https must be used to access the site sslstrip works also if the site is full https-only but the client does not know it.